# replace class name is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html segment

```js
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if ($("div.mm-panels").children()[i].getAttribute("id") == "m2") {
            var a = $("div.mm-panels").children()[i].getAttribute("class");
            console.log(a);
            var f = a.replace(a, "mm-panel mm-hasnavbar mm-opened");
            alert("class name chnge to : " + f);

        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mm-panels">
       <div class="mm-panel mm-hidden mm-hasnavbar" id="m0"></div>
       <div class="mm-panel mm-hasnavbar mm-opened" id="m1"></div>
       <div class="mm-panel mm-hidden mm-hasnavbar" id="m2"></div>
    </div>
```

and i want to find the children of mm-panel that have id="m2" and replace class names with  "mm-panel mm-hasnavbar mm-opened" and the other children replace class names by "mm-panel mm-hidden mm-hasnavbar".

but is not replacing. how can i do it ?

Comment: What is `s`. please include all relevant code

Comment: that is name of id od an element that is "m2". @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 1):

Your `replace` only replace the string "a" and save it into a new string "f".

To set the class of the element use `$("div.mm-panels").children()[i].setAttribute("class",f)`

```js
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if ($("div.mm-panels").children()[i].getAttribute("id") == "m2") {
            var a = $("div.mm-panels").children()[i].getAttribute("class");
            var f = a.replace(a, "mm-panel mm-hasnavbar mm-opened");
            $("div.mm-panels").children()[i].setAttribute("class",f)
        } else {
            var a = $("div.mm-panels").children()[i].getAttribute("class");
            var f = a.replace(a, "mm-panel mm-hidden mm-hasnavbar");
            $("div.mm-panels").children()[i].setAttribute("class",f)
        }
        
        
        $("div.mm-panels").children()[i].innerText = $("div.mm-panels").children()[i].getAttribute("class")
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mm-panels">
       <div class="mm-panel mm-hidden mm-hasnavbar" id="m0"></div>
       <div class="mm-panel mm-hasnavbar mm-opened" id="m1"></div>
       <div class="mm-panel mm-hidden mm-hasnavbar" id="m2"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: yes it is true . but how can i change class names of other children like m0 and m1 to "mm-panel mm-hidden mm-hasnavbar" ?

Answer (score 0):

As you used jQuery tag you can use [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add class and [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) to remove class. Try this:

```js
$("div.mm-panels").find(":not(div#md2)").removeClass("mm-panel mm-hasnavbar mm-opened").addClass("mm-panel mm-hidden mm-hasnavbar");
$("div.mm-panels").find("div#m2").removeClass("mm-panel mm-hidden mm-hasnavbar").addClass("mm-panel mm-hasnavbar mm-opened");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mm-panels">
   <div class="mm-panel mm-hidden mm-hasnavbar" id="m0">m0</div>
   <div class="mm-panel mm-hasnavbar mm-opened" id="m1">m1</div>
   <div class="mm-panel mm-hidden mm-hasnavbar" id="m2">m2</div>
</div>
```